# Google chrome disable same origin policy

Tags: php, google-chrome, jsonp

I've followed the tutorial as the link :

[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)

But when I add the shortcut target apparently always fail

Shortcut :

```
"C:\Users\Bertho Joris\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

When I add the line :

```
--disable-web-security
```

and results :

```
"C:\Users\Bertho Joris\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-web-security"
```

Always get an error message :

[image]

What should I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`"C:\Users\Bertho Joris\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security`

Take note of the location of the `""`

Comment: Do I have to remove the symbol "" ?

Comment: I tested it on my Chrome and it works. You have to change the target to the text i put in the answer.